# Button constraint issues i believe

Tags: android, android-studio, constraints, unchecked-cast

Hope the weekend is going well. I am working on  login and registration pages and having a hard time finding a solution to an **unchecked cast** error and after checking, it seemed everything is fine on the xml code. the challenge is really frustrating, Here is the code please

java code

```
public class RegistrationPage < Button > extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText emailId, password;
    Button btnSignin;
    TextView tvSign_Up;
    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration_page);

            mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            emailId = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextEmailAddress);
            password = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword);
            btnSignin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Sign_In);
            tvSign_Up = (findViewById(R.id.textView2));
            btnSignin.(new RegistrationPage < > () View.OnClickListener(("v"))) - > {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View "V") {
                        string email = emailId.getText().toString();
                        string pwd = password.getText().toString();
                        if (((String) email).isEmpty()) {
                            emailId.setError("Please Enter Correct Email Address");
                            emailId.requestFocus();
                        }
```

The xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".RegistrationPage">

<EditText
android:id="@+id/editTextTextEmailAddress"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="84dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="84dp"
android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="85dp"
android:layout_marginRight="85dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="313dp"
android:autofillHints=""
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/email"
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="85dp"
android:layout_marginRight="85dp"
android:autofillHints=""
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/password"
android:inputType="textPassword"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextEmailAddress"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.092" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
android:text="@string/already_have_an_account_sign_in_here"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.677" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/Sign_In"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
android:text="@string/sign_up"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.054" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any help will be appreciated greatly

Comment: What exactly is the error, exeption? Also where is editTextTextPassword on your xml?

Comment: Just edited post with xml aspect. Error is "unchecked cast"  thank you

Comment: Where is the unchecked cast happening exactly?

Comment: Here: btnSignin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Sign_In);

Comment: btnSignin.(new RegistrationPage<>() View.OnClickListener(("v"))) -> {

That line is wrong, RegistrationPage seems to be your activity, where are you compiling ?

Comment: On registration page

Comment: Can you add where you've declared `btnSignin`?

Comment: Have added this

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is some coding format errors. Replace your above java code with this and try it out:

```
mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
emailId = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextEmailAddress);
password = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword);
btnSignin = findViewById(R.id.Sign_In);
tvSign_Up = findViewById(R.id.textView2);

btnSignin.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    String email = emailId.getText().toString();
    String pwd = password.getText().toString();
    if (email.isEmpty()) {
        emailId.setError("Please Enter Correct Email Address");
        emailId.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error per se, it's a compile-time warning, sometimes warnings are irrelevant, sometimes they're not.

An alternative, *not solution* is to suppress that warning using

```
@SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
```

or

```
@Suppress("unchecked")
```

Before

```
btnSignin = findViewById(R.id.Sign_In); // remove (Button), is not necesary
```

> **SuppressWarning**
>
> `@SuppressWarnings` instruct the compiler to ignore or suppress the
> specified compiler warning in annotated element and all program
> elements inside that element, as an example, if a class is annotated
> to suppress a particular warning, then a warning generated during the
> methodology inside that class will also be suppressed.
>
> `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` and `@SuppressWarnings("serial")`
> are two of most popular samples of @SuppressWarnings annotation. Also
> if you limit the scope, this way it won’t even affect the entire
> method.
>
> SuppressWarnings indicates the potential programming error or mistake,
> so it's recommended to use them slenderly and instead attempt to solve
> actual problem which is triggering that warning. But there are
> situations when you are absolutely sure that things won't go wrong,
> you can use `@SuppressWarnings` to suppress those warnings.